# How to populate a TextView by reading .txt and replace previously existed .txt.?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development, doing a project, where I'm populating a textview with .txt file. Using same textview for several txt file.but problem is it's showing first second, third all text in that textview. It isn't clearing previous one.

```
  MenuModel menuModel = new MenuModel("Introduction", true, false, "Intro.txt");
    headerList.add(menuModel);

    menuModel = new MenuModel("Tense", true, true, "");
    headerList.add(menuModel);
    List<MenuModel> childModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    MenuModel childModel = new MenuModel("About Tense ", false, false, "TENSE.txt");
    childModelsList.add(childModel);
 if (menuModel.hasChildren) {
        childList.put(menuModel, childModelsList);
    }
```

I'm using expandable listview here
     private void populateExpandableList() {

```
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, headerList, childList);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            if (headerList.get(groupPosition).isGroup) {
                if (!headerList.get(groupPosition).hasChildren) {
```

setFile will select which text document to open

```
                    String setFile = headerList.get(groupPosition).url;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    try {
                        reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(setFile)));
                        String mLine;
                        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                            text.append(mLine);
                            text.append('\n');
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                //log the exception
                            }
                        }

                        TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
                        txtView.clearComposingText();
                        txtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                        txtView.setText(text);


                    }

                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            if (childList.get(headerList.get(groupPosition)) != null) {
                MenuModel model = childList.get(headerList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                if (model.url.length() > 0) {
```

setFile will select which text document to open

```
                    String setFile = model.url;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    try {
                        reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(setFile)));


                        String mLine;
                        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            text.append(mLine);
                            text.append('\n');
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                //log the exception
                            }
                        }
                        TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
                        txtView.clearComposingText();
                        txtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                        txtView.setText(text);

                    }
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the error with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `text` you use to store the file's lines is obviously a `StringBuilder` object isn't it? 
You use it to append each line after it's read from the file and when the reading is finished you set the `TextView`'s text to the text of the `StringBuilder`.
But prior to start reading the lines and appending them to the `StringBuilder` you must clear its previous text with

```
text = new StringBuilder();
```

or

```
text.setLength(0);
```

So put 1 of the above lines before the `while` loop.